# jupyter-notebook's top toolbar doesn't work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]
[image]
I push that buttons but anything happened.
I downloaded jupyter notebook again, but still it is not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide some details. All i see are two screenshots of a toolbar, a generic statement "it does not work" and that's it... (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What buttons are you pushing? What is your **specific** problem? Take a look at [this page](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
After I delete my ipython data, I can click the taskbar

`rm -rf ~/.ipython`